# How to turn off Feed Reading View in IE6?

Tags: internet-explorer, feed

I'm able to turn off Feed Reading View in IE8, but can't seem to find this option in IE6.

How can I turn off the Feed Reading?

Comment: why are you ie6 again?

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure IE 6 doesn't have a built in feed reader.